# difference between calling super and calling super()

Tags: ruby

What is the difference between calling super and calling super()? Which is the best one if the arguments passed to the child method don’t match what the parent is expecting.

Comment: What about the third possibility: `super('cat', 'dog', 'pig')`?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

When you call `super` with no arguments, Ruby sends a message to the parent of the current object, asking it to invoke a method with the same name as where you called `super` from, along with the arguments that were passed to that method.

On the other hand, when called with `super()`, it sends no arguments to the parent.

If the arguments you have don't match what the parent is expecting, then I would say you would want to use `super()`, or explicitly list parameters in the functional call to match a valid parent constructor.

Answer (score 33):

Dictates arguments that are sent up the object ancestor chain

```
super - sends all arguments passed to the function to parent
super() - no arguments
```

Comment: This is simpler!

Comment: can you provide an example please? what `all arguments` is referring to?

Comment: `all arguments` is any arguments that were passed to the function initially

Comment: This is interesting. It is the only use of empty`()` in ruby that I am aware of that is different from omitting `()`.

Answer (score 0):

super equals to super(*args), which brings all args to the inherited method
Use super() when you just want to call the method inherited from Parent without passing args

super example:

```
class Parent
  def say(message)
    p message
  end
end

class Child < Parent
  def say(message)
    super
  end
end

Child.new.say('Hello world!') # => "Hello world!"
```

super() examples:

```
class Parent
  def say
    p "I'm the parent"
  end
end

class Child < Parent
  def say(message)
    super
  end
end

Child.new.say('Hello!') # => ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0))


class Parent
  def say
    p "I'm the parent"
  end
end

class Child < Parent
  def say(message)
    super()
  end
end

Child.new.say('Hi!') # => "I'm the parent"
```